# How to recover my Firefox bookmarks from an unbootable laptop

Tags: ubuntu, data-recovery, firefox

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 two months ago and encrypted my partitions using Luks. Everything worked fine until today when I couldn't boot into my system. However I managed to get a copy my `home` folder booting into a live session and following [this](https://evilshit.wordpress.com/2012/10/29/how-to-mount-luks-encrypted-partitions-manually/) tutorial. To my surprise I realized I had not backed up my Firefox bookmarks.

So my question is: how can I get my bookmarks back?

Answer (score 2):

Look at `/home/*/.mozilla*/firefox/*/bookmarks.html`